# Literal Uri request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, uri

I've seen a number of posts that ask about using non-conforming Uris, but none of them have a good answer.  I'm writing a Windows Phone control and it needs to request ATOM data using HTTP GET.  The URL needs to include the characters %3d (the equal sign) in it.  This is non-negotiable as it's a third-party service over which I have no control.  Imagine a URL like the following:

http://host.com?arg1=val1&arg=val2%3d

I'm using WebClient with DownloadStringAsync, but it only accepts Uri objects, not URL in strings.  The Uri object automatically unescapes those characters and sends:

http://host.com?arg1=val1&arg=val2=

This fails.  There's a deprecated constructor argument "UserExcaped" that is exactly what I need, but it's not available.  I fear that my only option is to implement my own string download method using a raw socket and minimal HTTP support.

Any other thoughts?  Help is very much appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

    `string apps = "http://blah.com/api?prev=AAAAAAA%3d&next=BBBBBBB";
    var u = new Uri(apps);
    string apps2 = u.ToString();
    Debug.Assert(apps == apps2); // That %3d will always be converted to an equals sign`

I should also point out, that if I try to be clever by encoding the percent as %25 (so it's "prev=AAAAAA%253d&next=BBBBB") then I get that exact literal string with %25 still intact!  It's just %3d that it's aggressive about converting to an equals sign.

Comment: is there a way that you could set the pages Page ResponseEncoding="iso-8859-1" it sounds like an Encoding issue

Comment: Have you tried using HttpUtility.UrlEncode or HttpUtility.UrlDecode, etc.. ? I definitely hit servers with encoded paramaters, but im using the HttpWebRequest instead.

Comment: Hmmm...  I added an example to my question.  As soon as you try to construct a URI, it messes it up.

Comment: Not an answer, but it may help if you could not find the solution. My suggestion is to define and host your own webservice and call the third party's web service indirectly. This way your application is not  vulnerable to changes to webservice definition, also you could have a track of your application usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uri` class is designed to be like that. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

> As part of canonicalization in the constructor for some schemes,
>   escaped representations are compacted. The schemes for which URI will
>   compact escaped sequences include the following: file, **http**, https,
>   net.pipe, and net.tcp. For all other schemes, escaped sequences are
>   not compacted.

Have you tried using HttpWebRequest instead? It's a bit more work than a WebClient, but it lets you pass a string as the destination.

Edit - Another approach could be to create your own `UriParser` which allows the encoded version. An example of extending the `UriParser` can be [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/customuriparser.aspx).

For others **not** running Windows Phone, you can use `reflection` to fix this.

```
MethodInfo getSyntax = typeof(UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
FieldInfo flagsField = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (getSyntax != null && flagsField != null)
{
   foreach (string scheme in new[] { "http", "https" })
   {

       UriParser parser = (UriParser)getSyntax.Invoke(null, new object[] { scheme });
       if (parser != null)
       {
           int flagsValue = (int)flagsField.GetValue(parser);

           //0x20000 is the SimpleUserSyntax attribute
           if ((flagsValue & 0x20000) != 0)
              flagsField.SetValue(parser, flagsValue & ~0x20000);
       }
    }
}


Uri u = new Uri("http://host.com?arg1=val&arg=val2%3d");
//At this point, the %3d remains as expected.
```

Comment: I don't see that...  HttpWebRequest (at least on Windows Phone) uses the RequestUri property which is not string based...

Comment: @ArianKulp - Initiate a WebRequest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: So I just tried this out.  It does accept a string, but it apparently just constructs a Uri object internally since it performs the same escaping.  Argh!

Comment: I just had a go trying to fix it and I managed to get it working in a console app via reflection. I can clear the `SimpleUserSyntax` attribute and it works, but the problem is that Windows Phone throws an exception when I try the invoke the method via reflection. The `SimpleUserSyntax` attribute seems to be the issue.

Comment: @ArianKulp - You may be able to create your own UriParser and allow the encoded version: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/customuriparser.aspx

Comment: Nice.  Creating my own parser would likely do the trick.  Kinda crazy way to do it though!  I wish I could use reflection.  I wrote a Socket-based implementation and it works, but I hate re-inventing the wheel.  The new UriParser would enable me to use other framework tools (or Hammock) without further modification.  Thanks!  If you want to rewrite this as an answer I'll accept it.  I don't think there's another option.

Comment: I've added it to the answer. Sam's comment might help depending on feasibility, where you can send your string to your own web service and have that web service send the request on your behalf. You can use the reflection method above on your web service since it supports method invoking (unlike the phone).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock) - you should be able to give it a string rather than a Uri.

Comment: Nice looking framework.  I had never heard of it.  Same problem though.